# ruby paperclip error was received while processing .. not recognized by the 'identify' command - was working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I recently updated my working site and paperclip stopped working.  Some invesigation showed this in the logs:

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing:

Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/v9/xq0hq0wj4sq3849f_31qbbc80000gn/T/landing-writing20121218-58829-1tc98b3.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

Answer (score 1):

Many other answers deal with the paperclip path being wrong - this was not my case, as it was working until a recent 'bundle update' / release.

The issue was that I had locked Paperclip to version 3.2.0 (since they've had some 'breaking' releases in the past).  Paperclip depends on Cocaine in a non-locked version, which recently upgraded from 0.3 to 0.4.2.

Cocaine 0.4.2 doesn't work with paperclip 3.2.

Upgrading to paperclip 3.3.1 fixed the problem, I assume forcing cocaine to 0.3 in my gemfile would have fixed it as well.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I had. Slightly different version conflicts, but essentially the same issue. I was on Paperclip 2.5.2 and cocaine updated to 0.4.2; rolling back to cocaine 0.3.2 fixed this for me. Thank you!